# Login using ldap from reactjs app failing

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am trying to login from my Reactjs Application to Spring boot ldap(Authentication).

Though it's working but sometimes I am getting **401** Authentication error but in catch block which is weird.

Here is my code :

```
    fd.append('j_username', encodeURI(username))
    fd.append('j_password', encodeURI(password))

    try {

        const response = await axios({
            url: configs.Data.loginURL,
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data: fd,
            withCredentials: true
        });

        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 200) {

            return { loggedIn: true, error:'', status: response.status }
        } else {
            return { loggedIn: false, error:response.error, status: response.status }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return { status: err.response.status, error: err.response.statusText }
    }
```

Spring Security code

`protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()).and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(successHandler()).failureHandler(failureHandler()).usernameParameter("j_username").passwordParameter("j_password").permitAll().and().httpBasic().and()
.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler()).permitAll().and()
.headers().frameOptions().deny().and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/").permitAll()               .antMatchers("/admin/startProcess").access("hasAuthority('MANAGERS') or hasAuthority('SUPERUSER')").anyRequest().authenticated();}`

I am getting logged in successfully and sometimes I am going in catch block of my reactjs application.

[Auth error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbzmC.png)

[Success image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8apHk.png)

If I click login button first I am getting auth error and again then success. Alternative response are different for same endpoint

Comment: Please provide more info? Your React app is apparently correct maybe a problem in the backend?

Comment: @MehiShokri Yes but why I am getting authentication error only first login alternatively. Backend security code I have already shown

Comment: Check your request params for both successful and unsuccessful requests to see if they are exactly the same. If they are the same then the bug resides in the backend app. You can open another thread to discuss it.

Comment: @MehiShokri both are exactly same I have inspected network tab of chrome......the only change is status code.

Comment: Then it's not a problem related to your React app. Do something, open postman or whatever http client app you have (wget, curl) and test your api authentication with it. Most likely the bug lies within your backend code (Or maybe a problem related to your web-server, load balancer, etc.)